# Boot failure - goes to BusyBox - 'gave up waiting for boot device'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uuid

G'Day all
Have tried installing 14.04.1 LTS on its own partition, then emptying the whole HDD and putting on and having similar results -

```
'gave up waiting for boot device'
'/dev/disk/by-uuid/!longuid! does not exist'
```

...then it spits me out at initramfs.

The disk with the uuid is found when running from a live USB, and I have run boot-repair a few times without much luck - http://paste.ubuntu.com/8479183/.

it's on an ASUS U31F laptop (so no raid) and the bios looks like it can UEFI boot, if that has any relevance. Currently using a 14.04.1 Live USB on same laptop, so the hardware appears fine.

Any wisdom would be lovely!

**Update** - have tried g_p's advice, swapping the UUID for /dev/sda5 in GRUB, which resulted in /dev/sda5 not being found. When being dropped to shell (initramfs) I have been able to have a look inside /dev, but trying

```
ls /dev/[hs]da*
```

or

```
ls /*/[hs]da*
```

reveals nothing.

Running **blkid** in the **initramfs** prompt yields *nothing*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot without using the UUID. For this

- Highlight an old, working kernel from the Grub menu.
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> to  the menu entry for editing.
- Remove the entire `search` line. Use the <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Dn</kbd>  to placecursor at the start of the line and hold the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key to delete.
- On the `linux` line, change the part `root=UUID=<long number>` to `root=/dev/sdXY` with X being your Ubuntu drive and Y being your Ubuntu partition. .
  (*In your case it should be `root=/dev/sda5`*)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

If above method works, after booting open terminal and execute

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: g_p, thanks! although it didn't work, it now has '/dev/sda5 does not exist'. I'll keep digging around